# get Product Details from a Camera Intent in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, camera, barcode-scanner, android-camera-intent, detailsview

Is it possible to return the barcode value from the product details layout into my onActivityResult method? Or do I have to implement the scanner by myself?

I access my phone's camera from my app with the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Log.e(TAG, "nach intent");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    else {
    }
```

I am able to take a picture and the picture is returned to the onActivityResult method and displayed in my imageView.

My phone's camera is also able to detect barcodes. If a barcode is detected a "view details" button shows up and when I click it, the barcode is scanned automatically and the result is displayed in a product details layout.

I would like to return the product details result to my onActivityResult() method.

[image: product details layout]

Answer (score 0):

[Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) is a very popular library for scanning & extracting data from Barcode.

Alternatively you can use Google's own [Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview) which comes under Google's Mobile Vision APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know. I have already implemented a Barcode Scanner, but the product details result would be more convenient for my purpose